Can you calculate the distance to an object by the change in its relative size/distance travelled?
Say that youre travelling in a straight line towards a mountain, and at the beginning of the journey the mountain took up a certain amount of your field of view(x). After travelling 100km it takes up twice this amount. Can you calculate the remaining distance and/or the actual size of the object based off this information?

If you know $x$, you can.  Draw a diagram.  You have right triangles from the base of the mountain to the peak to your eye.  A bit of trig.  From far away, when the angle is small, it started 200 km away.

What's your definition of size? You know we have two dimensional vision. So the size would increase in two dimensions, so $x$ should have dimension of $ [L^2]$. Or is it only height/width wise?
